# On the Hilbert function of projective schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-schemes

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective subscheme (not necessarily reduced or irreducible). Denote by $I_X$ the ideal of $X$ i.e., $\Gamma_*(\mathcal{I}_X)$. There are two definitions of Hilbert functions that is used in the literature. One is the function $f(t)=\mbox{dim}(S/I_X)_t$, the $t$-graded part of the module where $S$ is the polynomial ring $k[X_0,...,X_n]$ and $t \in \mathbb{Z}$. The other definition is $f(t)=h^0(\mathcal{O}_X(t))$ for any integer $t$. Why are these two definitions compatible? I understand why they are the same for $t$ large enough.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what you are looking for.  You say that you know why they coincide—so what is missing from the picture?

Comment: I understand for t large enough as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the exact sequence $0 \to I_X \to S \to S/I_x \to 0$?

Comment: @Yongsu: Are you saying that $h^0(I_X(t))=\mbox{dim}(I_X(t))$ for all $t$? If so why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $I_X(t)=\Gamma_*\mathcal{I}_X(t)$ which is equal to $H^0(\mathcal{I}_X(t))$ by definition. Using the short exact sequence mentioned above, you get the equivalence of the two definitions.